# Could the Jewish Calendar be changed because of climate change?

Tags: calendar

It seems that certain parts of the Jewish calendar are based on specific observations.

I found this on Wikipedia, about the [old observational methods to adding leap months](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar#Leap_months) and it made me wonder if there were other areas of Jewish practices that could be impacted.

> The year may be intercalated on three grounds: aviv [i.e.the ripeness of barley], fruits of trees, and the equinox. On two of these grounds it should be intercalated, but not on one of them alone.

From Wikipedia, some of the [predicted impacts of climate change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_climate_change):

> Physical changes include extreme weather, glacier retreat, sea level rise, declines in Arctic sea ice, and changes in the timing of seasonal events (such as earlier spring flowering).

So in the case of the ripeness of barley, a longer warm season means barley sprouts, grows and ripens earlier. Fruit trees may also be impacted, which means 2 of the aforementioned criteria would be met.

So would the Jewish calendar be changed if climate change affected the aviv and fruit observations?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) ldrg and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us! This question might get closed but please don't let this discourage you from asking others or contributing to answers !

Comment: Really interesting question. I'd mention that it only applies to the original way of establishing leap years - which we hope to use again after we once more have a Sanhedrin. In the meantime the calendar has a mathematically calculated format that doesn't depend on anything at all except the number of the year.